# Issue When move to Fluent API, from Data annotations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

We are moving our asp .net core project. in clean architecture

In our old project we used Data Annotations to configure.

Now we use Fluent API,

I have a model

**This is a configuration we used in our old project**

DbContext.cs

`public DbSet<X> Xs { get; set; }`

X.cs

```
public class X     // This is a table
    {
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; private set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
        public List<Section> Sections { get; set; }   // not a table
 }
```

Section.cs   // not a table

```
public class Section
    {
       // does not have a Id (key)

        [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
        public List<PointsOfInterest> PointsOfInterests { get; set; }   // not a table
    }
```

PointsOfInterest.cs   // not a table

```
public class PointsOfInterest
    {
       // does not have a Id (key)

        public int Likes { get; set; }
    }
```

**And,Now I try to move Fluent API obove models.**

I have added a `Xconfiguration.cs` class.

DbContext.cs

`public DbSet<X> Xs { get; set; }`

Xconfiguration.cs

```
public class XConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<X>
{
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<X> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(i => i.Id);
        
        builder.Property(i =>i.Sections)
                .HasColumnType("jsonb");
    }

public class SectionConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Section>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Section> builder)
    {
        builder.HasNoKey();     // If I remove this line I got error while debugging. System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'Section' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'. For more information on keyless entity types, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2141943.
        
        builder.Property(i =>i.PointsOfInterests)
                .HasColumnType("jsonb");

    }
}
```

**The issue is when create a new migration, A Table named as Sections is created. I did not add public DbSet Xs { get; set; } into DbContext. Then Why Section Table is created?**

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Section",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    // removed
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                });
```

What is the mistake in my configurations? Why Section Table is created. Please someone help me to find the mistakes.
Thanks

Comment: Why do you have a `Column` attribute if your class is not a DB entity?

Comment: I saved Sections as json type  in a column

Comment: Yes, it makes sense for the `Sections` property of `X`. On the other hand, `Section` is not a DB entity (ie not a table), so why do you need a `Column` attribute on `PointsOfInterests`?

Comment: I feel like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations#composite-value-objects would fit here?

Comment: Yeah I did a mistake. So, I do not need to add `[Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]` above this line ` public List<PointsOfInterest> PointsOfInterests { get; set; } `